# Is there any way to use elasticsearch with mongoengine?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, mongoengine, django-haystack

I've got Django project using mongoengine. Large part of it uses aggregation pipeline queries to perform complex document search. I want to use elasticsearch in this project to speed up the search, but mainly for educational goal. I know that haystack is a good way to use ES in django projects, but it works with Django ORM only.

So is there any way to use ES with mongoengine django apps?